# Are there any means to change the FOV?

Tags: pc, state-of-decay

The game makes me motion sick. So is there any way to manipulate the FOV, be it ENB or any other hack? It surely isn't possible with the options or the config files.

Answer (score 2):

According to [PCGamingWiki](http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/State_of_Decay#Video_settings) there is no way to change the FOV, either using in-game options or config files. At least, at time of writing, nobody has found a way of changing it.

Comment: I am not looking for answers from Google, sorry. I am looking for answers from experts, that actually tried to change it.

Comment: good luck with that then